# Overhaul and start over area that was heavily overgrown

Tags: weed-control

I'm brand new to this forum, and I have recently acquired a fenced in backyard that had a corner of it totally overgrown with all kinds of stuff, such as huge weeds, wild vegetables, trees, plants, you name it. Basically, I would like to nuke the area and start over from scratch. I actually did remove everything and it's a dirt patch now, some things are starting to sprout with warm weather. I have only a few seasons of gardening experience, so I'm not sure what to do next.

The idea I am running with, putting down a weed barrier + mulch except for the fence perimeter where I would like to eventually plant things. My main concern is not wanting things to force their way through the weed barrier because I didn't catch all of it.

Comment: As commented on other similar questions, do try to give it a year in case anything interesting and good is hiding in there that you'd be unaware of in a frenzy of killing everything.

Comment: I have most of it documented, and I'm sure that I don't want any of it. Lots of wild onions, wild garlic, I've even found some star of Bethlehem. I plan to save some of the plants growing naturally on the fence line.

Comment: Don't use weed barrier unless you want to kill your soil - it prevents or severely restricts the exchange of oxygen between the atmosphere and the soil. And no fabric actually prevents weeds from growing through them, which is why they're now marketed (in the US at least) as landscape fabric, not weed barrier. See here for a discussion on the use of fabric (be sure to read the comments): https://gardenprofessors.com/?s=Landscape+Fabric+Strikes

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind, I think I will scale back the square footage of weed barrier to only areas I'm sure I need clear. Thanks for the advice!